# Extra single quote is appended in shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying to write a simple script that loads the iptables rules from a file to the iptables:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euxo pipefail
test_file="test.conf"
while read line; do
    echo $line
    echo "-----"
    iptables $line
done < $test_file
```

And the test.conf has some rules inside:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 123 -m comment --comment "test 1" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 112 -m comment --comment "test 2" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1231 -m comment --comment "test 3" -j ACCEPT
```

But when i run the script, it returns error as:

```
+ test_file=rules.conf
+ read line
+ echo -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 123 -m comment --comment '"test' '1"' 
-j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 123 -m comment --comment "test 1" -j ACCEPT
+ echo -----
-----
+ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 123 -m comment --comment '"test' 
'1"' -j ACCEPT
Bad argument `1"'
```

Looks like whenever the file is run and if there is a space in the string, it will have a single quote to wrap around the space.

Is there a way to get rid of the behavior?

Comment: What happens with `echo "$line"` `iptables "$line"` (always quote all your variables..) You can also add `while IFS= read line; do ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line is the main problem.  The shell doesn't interpret quote marks during variable expansion.  If you change that to

```
eval iptables $line
```

you should get (roughly) the right results.

Your read statement is also potentially problematic because you didn't set IFS to a newline first.  This could cause multiple whitespace to be collapsed and other possibly undesirable behavior.  So I would start with

```
IFS="
"
```

or similar.